# JTable Cells with HTML content sorting incorrectly

Tags: java, html, swing, jtable, rowsorter

I have a JTable with cells containing HTML for coloring and formatting. However, it is wrecking the sorting behavior. I have the Jsoup library ready to go to remove the HTML from the value, but I don't know where to insert the logic.

What's the quickest, easiest way to change this? I want to sort on the raw value text, not text with the HTML tags.

Comment: If you can, keep only the raw data in the model and use cell renderers to wrap the content in HTML...

Comment: Oh wow I never thought of that, that makes sense on pragmatic and philosophical levels.

Comment: Okay I did what MadProgrammer said and everything is less messy. It's common wisdom to separate the data model from the formatted view, it never occurred to me it applied to this situation too.